# Excel Sorting one column by Largest to Smallest string

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to sort each of my excel files by one column that has large length text. This is so the data isn't truncated when imported into SQL using data services job. I realise Excel reads the first 8 or 16 lines and determines the length of field based on that, a lot of my text was getting cut at 255 characters.

I tried one file as an experiment and the column was set at 399 varchar, which is the length of the longest string in one of the files. It doesn't matter what size of field I set in DS job mapping, the length of string experienced sets field size.

I have created a little snippet of VBA to loop through each file and sort by largest to smallest text, it is looping through and is doing something but is not sorting largest to smallest.

Not sure if it is empty cells or what that is causing it, however I managed to do this manually for one file - sort largest to smallest - now it never says largest to smallest, only A > Z for some reason.

I have one issue with the code, and that is as I mentioned it is not sorting, and 2) I have one concern about processing multiple files and determining max field length. I don't know if the DS job will alter the field size if it comes across another file with a larger text length than the last one? I done this with one file, but that doesn't tell me, the only way would be to try and properly sort multiple files, then run the job against each file.

Here is the loop wher eI am trying to also do the sort. I find the column called "sort Me" as an example then apply the sort to it.

```
 For i = 1 To lastcol

        With wb.ActiveSheet
            ColChar = colLtr(i)
            rangestr = ColChar & "1:" & ColChar & "" & MaxRowCount
             If .range(ColChar & 1).Value = "Sort Me" Then
                range(rangestr).Sort key1:=range(rangestr), order1:=xlDescending, Orientation:=xlSortRows, Header:=xlYes
            End If
        End With

    Next i
```

I have a function that creates the column character from the column number. I loop through each column till I hit the one I want then try and sort. the rangestr variable is the range I want to sort.

EDIT: To clarify I want text field longest at top and shortest at bottom, there are, nulls, some sheets have no text. Like this:

```
"This is the longest piece of text to be a top"
"This is shorter piece of text"
"This is even shorter"
```

Mainly would at least like to get the sorting done properly first. Seeking suggestions on how to do that properly.

Many thanks

Andrew

Comment: @Andrew...Its a bit unclear, what are you trying to sort by? The number of characters in each cells text in that particular column?

Comment: @dinotom yes....I've edited my original question to show what I want.

Comment: @Andrew...see the answer I posted

Comment: please post some example of data excerpt before and after sorting

Answer (score 1):

Excel has powerful built in sorting function that I'd  preferably use for both their actual speed and not to reinvent the wheel

given you need a new (and temporary) field - one with text length in it - I'd also use a "helper" field approach and code as follows:

```
Sub SortIt(dataRng As Range, headerStrng As String)
    Dim f As Range, helpRng As Range
    Dim colsOffset As Long

    With dataRng
        Set f = .Rows(1).Find(what:=headerStrng, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) '<--| look for wanted header column
        If f Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<--| if no header found, then no job to do!

        Set helpRng = .Resize(, 1).Offset(, .Parent.UsedRange.Columns(.Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column - .Columns(1).Column + 1) '<--| set a helper range in first column outside worksheet used range and occupying data range same rows
        With helpRng
            colsOffset = .Column - f.Column + 1 '<--| calculate column offset from "header" column to "helper" range
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=len(RC[-" & colsOffset - 1 & "])" '<--| fill "helper" range with corresponding "header" cells number of characters. they will be eventually cleared
        End With
        .Resize(, helpRng.Column - .Columns(1).Column + 1).Sort key1:=helpRng, order1:=xlDescending, Orientation:=xlSortColumns, Header:=xlYes
        helpRng.Clear '<--| clear the "helper" range
    End With
End Sub
```

to be called by your main sub as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim dataRng As Range, headerStrng As String

    With Worksheets("SortData") '<--| change "SortData" with your actual sheet name
        Set dataRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 10) '<--| change "A1", "A" and '10' to reflect, respectively, your  data actual leftupmost cell, "counter" column (i.e. the one that determines its rows span) and columns number
    End With
    headerStrng = "Sort me" '<--| change "Sort me" with your actual header

    SortIt dataRng, headerStrng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on a code snippet which I found [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=80743)
I edited the code as shown below, just pass in the range you want to sort and set the optional parameter to true if you want to sort by shortest length

```
Sub SortByLength(rangeToSort As Range, Optional shortest As Boolean = False)
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, lLastRow As Long
    Dim tempX As String, tempY As String
    Dim tempArray As Variant

    tempArray = rangeToSort
    'Sort array

    For x = 1 To UBound(tempArray)
        For y = x To UBound(tempArray)
            If shortest = True Then
                If Len(tempArray(y, 1)) < Len(tempArray(x, 1)) Then
                    tempX = tempArray(x, 1)
                    tempY = tempArray(y, 1)
                    tempArray(x, 1) = tempY
                    tempArray(y, 1) = tempX
                End If
            Else
                If Len(tempArray(y, 1)) > Len(tempArray(x, 1)) Then
                    tempX = tempArray(x, 1)
                    tempY = tempArray(y, 1)
                    tempArray(x, 1) = tempY
                    tempArray(y, 1) = tempX
                End If
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
    'Output sorted array
    Range(rangeToSort.Item(1), rangeToSort.Item(UBound(tempArray))) = (tempArray)

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Dinotom. I seem to be getting some cases where the data from other fields is being pulled to the top and put in wrapped text. I checked ID with original file, there is no comments, but in the test file there is about ten lines of short comments. 

I don't know if it is one text line split up or multiple ones. I know this has happened as when I look at the file the cell depths seem to have changed from normal line height to 10 or more line heights.

I would share the data but is sensitive and would lose my job for breaching data protection.

Comment: @Andrew...By other fields do you mean other cells in the range? The routine I posted should have no effect whatsoever on formatting. Try making sure the range you are passing to the sub is accurate.

Comment: Yes I mean other cells in the range seem to be getting moved about but the related data in other fields is not moving, I was a bit unsure about what I was actually passing as range, is it object or just a string? Not sure if this is right:

 Call SortByLength(.range(ColChar & "2:" & ColChar & "" & MaxRowCount))

Comment: Might it be better selecting the whole data set as the range and then sorting the column?

Comment: If you want to sort a range larger than the column your cell is in, then yes you do. Thats not what you indicated in the post.

Comment: I didn't know that's what I had to do when doing it through VBA.